# Как уникализировать список?

Tags: python

Есть такой список:

```
ls = [{'40', '39'},
      {'40', '39'},
      {'78', '82'},
      {'77', '81'},
      {'78', '82'},
      {'77', '81'},
      {'78', '82'}]
```

Я могу, конечно, его уникализировать через циклы, но хочется узнать, есть ли стандартный функционал в Python для этого?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Через множества:

```
ls = [{'40', '39'},
      {'40', '39'},
      {'78', '82'},
      {'77', '81'},
      {'78', '82'},
      {'77', '81'},
      {'78', '82'}]
print(set(map(frozenset, ls)))
```